# Derivative of a vec operator with respect to another vec operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let A be a symmetric matrix and $A^{-1}$ its inverse.
Denote $ a = \textrm{vec}[A] $.

Find the derivative of the following expression wrt $a$.

$$  \textrm{vec}^T[A^{-1}] - \textrm{vec}^T[A^{-1}BA^{-1}]$$

I know the result should be a symmetric matrix but I just can't get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\o{\otimes}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Defer vectorization until the **final** step and define the matrix function
$$\eqalign{
F &= \LR{\A-\A B\A} \qif \c{\A B\A=\LR{\A-F}} \\
}$$
First calculate the differential of the inverse of $A$
$$\eqalign{
I &= \A A \\
0 &= \A dA + d\A A \\
d\A &= {-\A\,dA\:\A} \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential of $F$
$$\eqalign{
dF
 &= {d\A-d\A B\A-\A B\,d\A} \\
 &= {-\A\,dA\:\A +\A\,dA\:\c{\A B\A}+\c{\A B\A}\,dA\:\A } \\
 &= {-\A\,dA\:\A +\A\,dA\CLR{\A-F}+\CLR{\A-F}dA\:\A } \\
 &= \;\;{\A\,dA\:\A -\A\,dA\:F-F\:dA\:\A } \\
}$$
**Now** vectorize the equation to recover the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
da &= \vc{dA} \\
df &= \vc{dF} \;=\; \LR{\A\o\A - F\o\A - \A\o F}da \\
\grad{f}{a} &= {\A\o\A - F\o\A - \A\o F} \\
}$$
To confirm the symmetry of this gradient, recall that for a Kronecker product
$$\LR{A\o B}^T = \LR{A^T\o B^T} $$

Comment: Neet. Great trick that I will definitely use in the future.